# Can I define classes in Django settings, and how can I override such settings in tests?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, overriding, django-settings

We are using Django for [Speedy Net and Speedy Match](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net) (currently Django 1.11.17, we can't upgrade to a newer version of Django because of one of our requirements, django-modeltranslation). I want to define some of our settings as classes. For example:

```
class UserSettings(object):
    MIN_USERNAME_LENGTH = 6
    MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH = 40

    MIN_SLUG_LENGTH = 6
    MAX_SLUG_LENGTH = 200

    # Users can register from age 0 to 180, but can't be kept on the site after age 250.
    MIN_AGE_ALLOWED_IN_MODEL = 0  # In years.
    MAX_AGE_ALLOWED_IN_MODEL = 250  # In years.

    MIN_AGE_ALLOWED_IN_FORMS = 0  # In years.
    MAX_AGE_ALLOWED_IN_FORMS = 180  # In years.

    MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 8
    MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 120

    PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'speedy.core.accounts.validators.PasswordMinLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'speedy.core.accounts.validators.PasswordMaxLengthValidator',
        },
    ]
```

(which is defined in https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/staging/speedy/net/settings/global_settings.py). And then in the models, I tried to use:

```
from django.conf import settings as django_settings

class User(ValidateUserPasswordMixin, PermissionsMixin, Entity, AbstractBaseUser):
    settings = django_settings.UserSettings
```

(and then use attributes of `settings`, such as `settings.MIN_USERNAME_LENGTH`, in the class).

But it throws an exception

```
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'UserSettings'
```

(but it doesn't throw an exception if I use there a constant which is not a class).

This is the first problem. In the meantime, I defined instead:

```
from speedy.net.settings import global_settings as speedy_net_global_settings

class User(ValidateUserPasswordMixin, PermissionsMixin, Entity, AbstractBaseUser):
    settings = speedy_net_global_settings.UserSettings
```

The second problem, is how do I override such settings in tests? For example, I use the following code:

```
from speedy.core.settings import tests as tests_settings

@override_settings(MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRIENDS_ALLOWED=tests_settings.OVERRIDE_MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRIENDS_ALLOWED)
```

in https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/staging/speedy/core/friends/tests/test_views.py. But if `MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRIENDS_ALLOWED` would be defined in the class `UserSettings`, how do I override it?

Comment: Why do you want to use a class? Why not a dict?

Comment: I thought because with a class I can inherit them and change only what I want. But it's possible to do something similar with dictionaries. A class is also more readable in the code. Anyway, I would like to know how to override settings also with dictionaries.

Comment: @Uri: Take a look at how [`modify_settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/test/utils/#modify_settings) does it for lists and make similar operations for dictionaries. If you want to do "inheritance", I've found making a `settings` module and creating submodules works just as well, with `settings/__init__.py` doing `from .submodule import *; OVERRIDE_THING = True` to simulate inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Blender for the tip:

> Django's settings object explicitly skips over any objects in your
>   settings module with non-uppercase names. If you rename your class to
>   USER_SETTINGS, it will work.

I was not aware that all the settings have to be uppercase. So I renamed `class UserSettings` to `class USER_SETTINGS` (although PyCharm doesn't like it), but I checked and it's also possible to add this code at the end of the file:

```
USER_SETTINGS = UserSettings
```

Without renaming the class.

As for my second question - how do I override such settings in tests? I added a file called `utils.py`:

```
def get_django_settings_class_with_override_settings(django_settings_class, **override_settings):
    class django_settings_class_with_override_settings(django_settings_class):
        pass

    for setting, value in override_settings.items():
        setattr(django_settings_class_with_override_settings, setting, value)

    return django_settings_class_with_override_settings
```

(You can see it on https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/staging/speedy/core/base/test/utils.py)

And then in the tests:

```
from django.conf import settings as django_settings
from django.test import override_settings

from speedy.core.settings import tests as tests_settings
from speedy.core.base.test.utils import get_django_settings_class_with_override_settings

    @override_settings(USER_SETTINGS=get_django_settings_class_with_override_settings(django_settings_class=django_settings.USER_SETTINGS, MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRIENDS_ALLOWED=tests_settings.OVERRIDE_USER_SETTINGS.MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRIENDS_ALLOWED))
    def test_user_can_send_friend_request_if_not_maximum(self):
        self.assertEqual(first=django_settings.USER_SETTINGS.MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRIENDS_ALLOWED, second=4)
```

I checked and I have to define another class (in this case, `class django_settings_class_with_override_settings` because if I change the class `django_settings_class` directly it also affects other tests which didn't use `@override_settings`.

Answer (score 3):

Django doesn't expect you to deviate much from its low-level design choices and it's usually a struggle to work around things that Django doesn't explicitly allow you to customize.

1. Django's settings object [explicitly skips over](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/conf/__init__.py#L119) any objects in your settings module with non-uppercase names. If you rename your class to `USER_SETTINGS`, it will work. If you *really* want to keep your object's original name a horrible solution would be to trick Django:

   ```
   class UserSettings:
       ...

   class AlwaysUppercaseStr(str):
       def isupper(self):
           return True

   globals()[AlwaysUppercaseStr('UserSettings')] = globals().pop('UserSettings')
   ```

   I have no idea if this is portable across Python implementations but it works with CPython's `dir()`.
2. `override_settings` has no support for what you're trying to do so you will probably need to rewrite that class to allow the global `settings` object to be configurable.