# Overriding settings in Django when used by the models

Tags: python, django, overriding, django-settings

We are using Django for [Speedy Net and Speedy Match](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net) (currently Django 2.1). Some of our settings are used by the models. For example:

```
class USER_SETTINGS(object):
    MIN_USERNAME_LENGTH = 6
    MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH = 40

    MIN_SLUG_LENGTH = 6
    MAX_SLUG_LENGTH = 200

    # Users can register from age 0 to 180, but can't be kept on the site after age 250.
    MIN_AGE_ALLOWED_IN_MODEL = 0  # In years.
    MAX_AGE_ALLOWED_IN_MODEL = 250  # In years.

    MIN_AGE_ALLOWED_IN_FORMS = 0  # In years.
    MAX_AGE_ALLOWED_IN_FORMS = 180  # In years.

    MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 8
    MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 120

    MAX_NUMBER_OF_FRIENDS_ALLOWED = 800

    PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'speedy.core.accounts.validators.PasswordMinLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'speedy.core.accounts.validators.PasswordMaxLengthValidator',
        },
    ]
```

(which is defined in https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/staging/speedy/net/settings/global_settings.py). And then in the models I use:

```
from django.conf import settings as django_settings

class User(ValidateUserPasswordMixin, PermissionsMixin, Entity, AbstractBaseUser):
    settings = django_settings.USER_SETTINGS
```

(and then use attributes of `settings`, such as `settings.MIN_SLUG_LENGTH`, in the class).

The problem is, when I try to override such settings in tests (you can see my question & answer on [Can I define classes in Django settings, and how can I override such settings in tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942999/can-i-define-classes-in-django-settings-and-how-can-i-override-such-settings-in)), `User.settings` remains the same and is not overridden by the settings I tried to override. This is a problem since in the model I passed `settings.MIN_SLUG_LENGTH` for example to validators, which are also passed other values by other models. Is it possible to define the models and settings in such a way which the correct settings will be used both in production and in tests, including when I want to override them?

I'm aware of this quote from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings:

> **Warning**
>
> The settings file contains some settings that are only consulted
>   during initialization of Django internals. If you change them with
>   override_settings, the setting is changed if you access it via the
>   django.conf.settings module, however, Django’s internals access it
>   differently. Effectively, using override_settings() or
>   modify_settings() with these settings is probably not going to do what
>   you expect it to do.
>
> We do not recommend altering the DATABASES setting. Altering the
>   CACHES setting is possible, but a bit tricky if you are using
>   internals that make using of caching, like django.contrib.sessions.
>   For example, you will have to reinitialize the session backend in a
>   test that uses cached sessions and overrides CACHES.
>
> Finally, avoid aliasing your settings as module-level constants as
>   override_settings() won’t work on such values since they are only
>   evaluated the first time the module is imported.

Which I understand are relevant in this case, but how do I define the settings in such a way that I can override them?

Function [`_1___set_up`](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/staging/speedy/core/base/test/models.py#L48-L53) in speedy/core/base/test/models.py is a workaround to make the tests work, but this is a hack and I don't think it's a good solution for the long term.

Comment: Do you really need `USER_SETTINGS` to be a class, or can it be an instance of a class?

Comment: @aaron I don't know. Currently it's a class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem, as you quoted:

> avoid aliasing your settings as module-level constants as `override_settings()` won’t work on such values since they are only evaluated the first time the module is imported.

There are 3 ways around this, where **Way 1** > **Way 3** > **Way 2**.

## Way 1: Don't alias with class attribute, but `classproperty`

Recommended; arguably the correct way.

- Pro: Most expressive, easier to debug.
- Con: More code in model.

```py
from django.utils.decorators import classproperty

class User(PermissionsMixin, Entity, AbstractBaseUser):
    # settings = django_settings.USER_SETTINGS
    @classproperty
    def settings(cls):
        return django_settings.USER_SETTINGS
```

**Caveat**: Class attributes that depend on the `settings` class attribute won't work.

Although **Way 2** allows the following code to still be valid, these are evaluated at class definition (import) time and cannot reasonably change based on `override_settings()`, unless they are `classproperty` too.

```py
AGE_VALID_VALUES_IN_MODEL = range(settings.MIN_AGE_ALLOWED_IN_MODEL, settings.MAX_AGE_ALLOWED_IN_MODEL)
AGE_VALID_VALUES_IN_FORMS = range(settings.MIN_AGE_ALLOWED_IN_FORMS, settings.MAX_AGE_ALLOWED_IN_FORMS)
```

## Way 2: Patch settings class so instances read `django_settings`

Not recommended; *impacts the runtime evaluation of USER_SETTINGS also in production, not only in tests (@hynekcer)*.

- Pro: No code change in model.
- Con: Least expressive, more difficult to debug.

1. Define a function `overridable_settings`:

```py
def overridable_settings(settings_class):
    old__getattribute__ = settings_class.__getattribute__
    settings_name = settings_class.__name__

    def patched__getattribute__(_self, item):
        from django.conf import settings as django_settings
        settings = getattr(django_settings, settings_name)
        return old__getattribute__(settings, item)

    settings_class.__getattribute__ = patched__getattribute__
    return settings_class()
```

2. `django_settings.USER_SETTINGS` is now an instance of the settings class. Instead of `get_django_settings_class_with_override_settings`, define `override_settings`:

```py
import copy

def override_settings(settings, **overrides):
    copied_settings = copy.deepcopy(settings)
    for setting, value in overrides.items():
        setattr(copied_settings, setting, value)
    assert copied_settings != settings
    return copied_settings
```

Usage:

```py
@overridable_settings
class USER_SETTINGS(object):
```

```py
from speedy.core.base.test import utils

# @override_settings(USER_SETTINGS=get_django_settings_class_with_override_settings(django_settings_class=django_settings.USER_SETTINGS, MIN_SLUG_LENGTH=tests_settings.OVERRIDE_USER_SETTINGS.MIN_SLUG_LENGTH))
@override_settings(USER_SETTINGS=utils.override_settings(django_settings.USER_SETTINGS, MIN_SLUG_LENGTH=tests_settings.OVERRIDE_USER_SETTINGS.MIN_SLUG_LENGTH))
def test_slug_min_length_fail_username_min_length_ok(self):
```

## Way 3: Create receiver of signal `setting_changed` to update alias

- Pro: Minimal code change to model.
- Con: Less expressive than **Way 1** with regard to the dependent attributes in the **Caveat**.

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings:

> When overriding settings, make sure to handle the cases in which your app’s code uses a cache or similar feature that retains state even if the setting is changed. Django provides the [`django.test.signals.setting_changed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.test.signals.setting_changed) signal that lets you register callbacks to clean up and otherwise reset state when settings are changed.
>
> Django itself uses this signal to reset various data.

```py
from django.core.signals import setting_changed
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

def register_django_setting_alias(setting_alias, django_setting):
    def decorator(cls):
        @receiver(setting_changed, weak=False)
        def update_setting_alias(setting, value, **_):
            if setting == django_setting:
                setattr(cls, setting_alias, value)
        return cls
    return decorator
```

Usage:

```py
@register_django_setting_alias('settings', 'USER_SETTINGS')
class User(PermissionsMixin, Entity, AbstractBaseUser):
    settings = django_settings.USER_SETTINGS
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please give me some time to check this solution.

Comment: I used your way 1 and it works. I just wanted to ask you, I found out that Django uses `cls` as the variable (class) name for methods decorated with `@classproperty` (and not `self`). Isn't it better to use `cls`? I also used `cls` in my code to be similar to the code of Django.

Comment: I didn't use your way 2 because you recommended to use way 1.

Comment: You can see my commits in branch `staging`: https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/commits/staging

Comment: Yes, it's better to use `cls`. I've updated my answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: The "Way 2" has three disadvantages: 1. The decorator `overridable_settings()` impacts the runtime evaluation of USER_SETTINGS also in production, not only in tests. Access to all attributes including builtin magic methods is more complicated. 2. The class USER_SETTINGS is broken at startup until Django settings configuration is completed. 3. A nested `override_settings()` is broken by this way if some overriding is applied e.g. to a test case class and an overriding of an additional attribute is applied to a test method, then the older overriding is forgotten.

Comment: Both ways seems however sufficient for that project.

Comment: A solution with a signal [`setting_changed()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#setting-changed) is possible. A registered receiver of that signal will get information about the name the changed setting, among other information.

That solution would be little more complicated than  
`@classproperty`  
`def settings(self): return django_settings.USER_SETTINGS`  
in this answer (that has a minimal time overhead) but can be very useful if something more time consuming that depends on the settings must be prepared at startup and cached until an eventual `override_settings'.

Comment: @hynekcer Thanks for the feedback and sharing about the signal `setting_changed`. It's less expressive than Way 1 with regard to the dependent attributes in the Caveat, but cleaner than Way 2 with regard to the three (additional) disadvantages that you pointed out.

Comment: @aaron I admire your tricky solution Way 2 that it restores the original settings value also if someone will jump in debugger from the body of test method to the main Python command line, though it seemed impossible to satisfy this way.

Comment: @hynekcer Do you mind explaining how Disadvantage 3 breaks `override_settings()`? I can reproduce that but haven't been able to pinpointed why that happens.

Comment: I'm going to explain it by a longer answer where I also fix it. A comment format is too short.

Comment: @hynekcer @Uri I've updated my answer with Way 3, which uses the signal `setting_changed`.

Comment: @aaron ad problem 3: Nested overrides on the same sub-setting can't be combined by no method. It can't be fixed because the call of context decorator [`override settings`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/753b67c58de8021487af7cafa4241e8326aa5508/django/test/utils.py#L381) creates only almost empty context manager first when a module is loaded without known context where it is applied. The context with the method decorated including the previous overriding applied to it yet is known to the decorator much later by the method `override_settings.__call__`. It is too late to combine anything.

Comment: @aaron You can see that [override settings applied to to TestCase](https://github.com/django/django/blob/753b67c58de8021487af7cafa4241e8326aa5508/django/test/utils.py#L444-L447) are applied as dictionary merge of previous overrides with options. [override settings applied to test method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/753b67c58de8021487af7cafa4241e8326aa5508/django/test/utils.py#L403-L407) are applied directly to a copy of settings with previous override applied. It is too late and so all customization to the same sub-settings class must be applied together